# Proving that $S_n/n$ converges in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have been struggling with the practice problem below for the past week. Could you help me how to solve this?

$X_1,X_2, \cdots$ are sequence of independent random variables. $X_1=0$, and for $n\geq 2, P(X_n=0)=1-\frac{1}{n\textrm{ln}(n)}, P(X_n=n)=P(X_n=-n)=\frac{1}{2n\textrm{ln}(n)}$. We also define $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$.

Then,

1. Does $S_n/n$ converge in probability to a limit?
2. Does $S_n/n$ converge almost surely to a limit?

I have been trying to use the law of large number to solve this problem, but I can't really apply the law of large number because $X_i$'s are not iid. On the other hand, I found this theorem below which I think can be used to solve this problem, but I am having trouble applying the theorem. The theorem is:

Let $\{X_{n,k}\}_{1\leq k\leq n}$ be a triangular array of random variables such that $X_{n,1},...X_{n,n}$ are independent for each $n$. Let $b_n > 0$ such that $b_n \rightarrow \infty$, and let $\bar{X}_{n,k} = X_{n,k}1_{|X_{n,k}| \leq b_n}$. (Here, $1_{|X_{n,k}| \leq b_n}$ is an indicator variable). Suppose as $n \rightarrow \infty$,
(1) $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(|X_{n,k}| >b_n) \rightarrow 0$
(2) $b_n^{-2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}E({\bar{X}_{n,k}}^2) \rightarrow 0$
Define $S_n=X_{n,1}+ \cdots + X_{n,n}$ and $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}E(\bar{X}_{n,k})$,
then $\frac{S_n-a_n}{b_n}$ converges in probability to $0$.

How can I solve this?

Thank you,

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3074422/321264

Answer (score 1):

The answer to question 1 is that $S_n/n \to 0$ in probability.  This can be proved with a simple application of [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality).  Since the $X_i$ are independent and satisfy $\mathbb{E}(X_j) = 0$, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}(S_n^2) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}(X_j^2) = \sum_{j=2}^{n} j^2 \cdot \frac{1}{j\log j} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{j}{\log j} \leq n \cdot \frac{n}{\log n} = \frac{n^2}{\log n}.
$$
Therefore Chebyshev's inequality says
$$
\mathbb{P}(|S_n| > n\epsilon) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(S_n^2)}{(n\epsilon)^2} \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^2 \log n} \to 0
$$
for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$.

I don't know the answer to question 2...it's very interesting and I'll keep thinking about it